# Is it possible to add description to the editable grid cell?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

I have been trying to use everything that came to my mind this last hour to do this.

I have an editable cell that renders empty, but once you click on it, the combo box will open and after the selection will show that value in the cell.

**The issue is that the cell renders empty and it can be confusing for some users since there is no description telling them "to click on the cell to select from combo box". I do not want to use tooltip. I would rather have a description in the cell and when user clicks on it and selects from combo, that will disappear and instead the selected value will be visible.**

How can I do this? I tried to use `renderer`, but it always stays on top, even after selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a condition in the renderer:

```
renderer: function(value) {
    if (value) {
        return value;
    }
    return 'description';
}
```

or

```
renderer: function(value) {
    return Ext.util.Format.defaultValue(value, 'description');
}
```